# Workaround to read response from write

Tags: bluetooth, web-bluetooth

From https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothremotegattcharacteristic-writevalue, I see that writeValue returns a DataView, but I keep getting null on my Chrome (Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit) on High Sierra).

What I do is as below, status from writeValue() is null, and value from readValue() is an empty DataView:

```
let status = await wifiChar.writeValue(encoder.encode(wifiValue));
console.log('status: ', status)
let value = await wifiChar.readValue();
console.log('value: ', value)
```